# Understanding callbacks with http.get in node

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

New node programmer here and I'm having a rough time understanding how to return the contents of a http request from a function due to the async nature of node. Here is a stripped down version of my program.

```
//#1
function getwebsite(url) {
    var body;
    http.get(url, function (res) {
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
            //***Right here, I need 'body' returned out of this function***
        });
    });
}


//#2
var a = getwebsite('website1.com');
var b = getwebsite('website2.com');

//#3
console.log(a+b);
```

All that I want to do is 1: create a function that grabs data from a site (in case it matters, its JSON and XML), 2: be able to call that function from anywhere in my program, 3: be able to manipulate whatever data has been returned out of my function.

The way that you are supposed to place (and call) the callback function makes my head hurt. I've studied dozens of examples of both http.get and just general callback samples but haven't found one yet where the two merge like in my sample. After a days worth of failed attempts, I feel like like if someone could show how to do this in my example it may finally click in my brain (fingers crossed).

Comment: You want a Deferred (a Promise is also a Deferred), and `.then()` or `.when()`. Node.js should have documentation (I'm not a Node developer, but this is a common pattern in Javascript). EDIT: [You might try this tutorial.](http://howtonode.org/promises)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My understanding from tutorials (including the one you linked) is that Promise has been dropped from Node. I'm not sure why because it looks incredibly useful. However I feel like at this point I should force myself to understand callbacks (which is a big part of the async nature of Node) before I dive into plugins.

Comment: You didn't understand what was being said; the implementation was dropped from Node.js *because it wasn't well implemented*, not because Node.js won't "support" Deferreds. The operable terminology was *left it for an exercise in userland* meant it would not be a Node.js native offering, but libraries that provide their functionality are still viable and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the base pattern you want to employ for plain callback style:

```
function getwebsite(url, cb) {
    var body = "";
    http.get(url, function (res) {
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk.toString();
            // you can't return a value from this function
            // the return value would be swallowed by the function
            // that is calling this function
            // which is not your code, but internal Node.js code
        });
        res.on("end", function() {
          cb(null, body)
        })
        res.on("error" function(error) {
          cb(error)
        })
    });
}

getwebsite("a", function(error, contentsA) {
  if (error) throw "Error getting website A."
  getwebsite("b", function(error, contentsB) {
    if (error) throw "Error getting website B."
    console.log(contentsA)
    console.log(contentsB)
  })
})
```

You may also want to look into flow-control libraries like [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) (or my promise-based [Faithful](https://github.com/meryn/faithful)), or general-purpose promise libraries like [RSVP.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js).
I recommend first getting accustomed with the basics of callbacks though.

For simple http requests, it's much easier to use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. You won't have to bind event listeners then. You just have a function that you can use in a similar way to the `getwebsite` function (which has issues!).

To get acquainted with async programming, you may want to try reading and writing some files with `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile`. For example, try to write contents of file A to file B. These are pretty simple functions, but you need to handle the callback-flow right. Node's http module is relatively complex in comparison. Or use the request module for that, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling out console.log() before the data has had a chance to return. You could bring the body variable to a higher scope and append to that. ie

```
var body;

function getwebsite(url) {
    http.get(url, function (res) {

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
            //***Right here, I need 'body' returned out of this function***
            outputBody(body);
        });
    });
}
var a = getwebsite('website1.com');
var b = getwebsite('website2.com');

function outputBody(val){
    console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the issue is that I don't actually want to call console.log, I want to be able to manipulate the data (a and b) outside of the function, I just threw the console in there as an example of how I could do something with both variables at the same time. Pretend in the example you've given we replace 'console.log(body);' with 'return body;'. What is the syntax that would allow that to actually work?

Comment: @jwhazel, by the time you design what you're describing (which cannot be done with procedural code in asynchronous callbacks), you would have built a (probably limited) Deferred or Promise. A Deferred pattern more or less sets up a common observer between dependent processes that, as the callbacks return to that object and are observed, when the observable contract is fulfilled (all promises fulfilled or otherwise handled in a set amount of time), another function is called that merges or does whatever that requires the functions to have been observed as terminating.

Comment: The console.log in the last line won't work. That is, it will log nothing, since body has not been filled yet.